# yum/rpm: exclude a file (by path) from being installed

Tags: yum, rpm

Is there any way to make yum/rpm never install a particular file path, but to otherwise install any packages which contain that file path, and for verification to act as if that file exists?  For example, a certain package puts a file in `/etc/cron.daily` that I don't want.  I figured out a hack for that particular issue, but it seems like it might be something that could come in handy in other circumstances.

**EDIT**: I tried using [RPM filetriggers](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/RPM_filetriggers) to delete the file right after it was installed, but it didn't do anything.  Plus it would probably have failed the yum verification step.

Comment: Once check SRPM => http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

Comment: I don't want to have to rebuild an entire RPM from source just to exclude a single file from being installed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **--excludepath=** option, for instance if you have this kind of error:

```
$ sudo rpm -i chromium-27.0.1453.110-202711.x86_64.rpm
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/share/applications/chromium-devel.desktop;569df493: cpio: open failed - Permission denied
```

you can use the option like this:

```
$ sudo rpm -i chromium-27.0.1453.110-202711.x86_64.rpm --excludepath=/usr/share/applications/chromium-devel.desktop
# works ok
```